# MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3 not compatible with MvvmCross.Droid.Support.v7.AppCompat 5.6.3

Tags: android, mvvmcross

MvvmCross.Droid.Support.v7.AppCompat 5.6.3
Depends on
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (>=25.3.1)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 26.1.0.1
Depends on
MonoAndroid, Version=**v8.0**

MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3
Depends on
MonoAndroid,Version=**v0.0**

Question:
How can I use both MvvmCross.Droid.Support.v7.AppCompat 5.6.3 and MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused 5.6.3 in the same project when they depend on different versions of MonoAndroid?
Thanx,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

`MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` is broken until 6.0.0.
See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2633#issuecomment-368532014

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` with MvvmCross version 5.6.3 if you use `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` version 42.1021.1. You will have to wait for the release of MvvmCross 6.0 to use `MvvmCross.Plugin.Location.Fused` against the latest `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` version, which is 60.1142.0 when this was written.